# List to Pandas dataframe where dimensions of dataframe have to be specified

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert a list to a dataframe.
list = [ '1', '2' , '3','4','5','6','7','8',....]

and I want to have 4 columns, so the dataframe looks like

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

etc.

Kind regards,

Wokter

Comment: you want to convert every 4 elements to a row?

Answer (score 2):

This would be one way:

1. First create a list of lists with the N-sized chunks (N=4 in this case).
2. Then create the dataframe.

```
l = list(range(1,41))
def chunks(l, n):
    """
    Yield successive n-sized chunks from list l.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

N = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(list(chunks(l, N)))
```

Result will be:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
4  17  18  19  20
5  21  22  23  24
6  25  26  27  28
7  29  30  31  32
8  33  34  35  36
9  37  38  39  40
```

Answer (score 1):

use **numpy** to **pad** it and **reshape** it

```
import math
l = [ '1', '2' , '3','4','5','6','7','8', '9']
pd.DataFrame(np.pad(np.array(l),(0,4-len(l)%4)).reshape(math.ceil(len(l)/4), 4))
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Use **[np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html?highlight=array_split#numpy.array_split)** if the size of your list can't be divided evenly

```
l= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(l,(4,-1)))

   0     1     2     3
0  1     2     3     4
1  5     6     7     8
2  9  None  None  None
```

**fillna()** if you need to fill None values

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(l,(4,-1))).fillna(0)

   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
2  9  0  0  0
```